# localnotification is not displayed as popup

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is there any reason why my local notification is displayed in notification centre but not POPED up? Is there any setting to make it popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local notification will be displaid as all other notifications, there is nothing you as a Developer can do about it.

The default settings for notification is to display them as a banner at the top of the screen, not like a alert view as in previous version of iOS.

Only the user can set the display style in the settings app notification section.

Comment: Is there a way I can make it to pop in simulator?

Comment: No, the simulator does not provide any means to change the way notification are presented.